# On existence of a nonzero integer vector $x$ such that $\|Bx\|_1\leq \sqrt[n]{n!\,|\det(B)|}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

> Let $B=(b_{ij})$ be a real invertible $n\times n$ matrix for some $n\ge2$. Prove that there exists an integer vector $(x_1,\cdots, x_n)^T\ne0$ such that $\|Bx\|_1\leq\sqrt[n]{n!\,|\det(B)|}$.

There are several inequalities that might be useful for this problem: Holder's inequality, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for inner products, the AM-GM inequality, the power-mean inequality, and Jensen's inequality. I also know that $\det(B) = \sum_{\sigma \in \Pi_n}(-1)^\sigma b_{1, \sigma(1)}b_{2,\sigma(2)}\cdots b_{n,\sigma(n)},$ where $\Pi(n)$ is the set of permutations of $\{1,\cdots, n\}$ and that it can be obtained from cofactor expansion along any row or column, which might be useful for proving this inequality.

Comment: are you sure the upper bound isn't $\sqrt[n]{n!\cdot \vert \det(B)\vert }$.  I don't see anything in the problem statement precluding e.g. $\det(B) =-1$.

Comment: @user8675309 I've modified the problem accordingly.

Comment: Might this follow from Minkowski's results in [the geometry of numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry_of_numbers)?

Answer (score 4):

This follows from Minkowski's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry_of_numbers

Let $r > 0$ and $K_r$ be the compact set $\{x \in \mathbb R^n : \lVert B x \rVert_1 \leq r\}$. We have $\operatorname{Vol}(K_r) = \frac{(2r)^n}{n! \cdot\lvert\det(B)\rvert}$.

Because $K_r$ is closed, by Minkowski's theorem it contains a non-zero integer vector as soon as $\operatorname{Vol}(K_r) \geq 2^n$. That is, as soon as
$$r \geq \sqrt[n]{n! \cdot \lvert \det(B) \rvert} \,.$$

To compute $\operatorname{Vol}(K_r)$, it suffices to do this when $r = 1$ and $B$ is the identity matrix. Then you want to compute $2^n$ times the volume of the set
$$\{(x_i) \in [0, 1]^n : x_1 + \cdots + x_n \leq 1\} \,.$$
Using Fubini's theorem you can show by induction that it is $\frac1{n!}$.

Comment: If possible could you provide a proof or a link to a proof of Minkowski's theorem? I think it would be useful to know that.

Comment: Could you justify why it suffices to compute $Vol(K_r)$ when $r=1$ and $B=I$?

Comment: @FredJefferson In fact, the proof is on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_theorem#Proof . For the volume, you can first reduce to $r = 1$ by replacing $B$ by $B \cdot r^{-1/n}$. You can then make a change of variables in the integral to reduce to $B = 1$. The determinant of $B$ shows up in the substitution rule.